# Python: how to improve a normalization algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, normalization

I have a `list` `X` containg the data performed by different users `N` so the the number of the user is `i=0,1,....,N-1`. Each entry `Xi` has a different length.
I want to normalize the value of each user `Xi` over the global dataset `X`.

This is what I am doing. First of all I create a `1D` list containing all the data, so:

```
tmp = list()
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    tmp.extend(X[i])
```

then I convert it to an array and I remove outliers and `NaN`.

```
A = np.array(tmp)
A = A[~np.isnan(A)] #remove NaN
tr = np.percentile(A,95)
A = A[A < tr]  #remove outliers
```

and then I create the histogram of this dataset

```
p, x = np.histogram(A, bins=10) # bin it into n = N/10 bins
```

finally I normalize the value of each users over the histogram I created, so:

```
Xn  = list()
for i in range(0,len(X)):
    tmp = np.array(X[i])
    tmp = tmp[tmp < tr]
    tmp = np.histogram(tmp, x)
    Xn.append(append(tmp[0]/sum(tmp[0]))
```

My data set is very large and this process could take a while. I am wondering if there is e a better way to do that or a package.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, if each element `X[i]` of `X` is a list, you may be able to use `sum`, and then convert directly to an array, or use `concatenate`:

```
# Example X
X = [list(range(i)) for i in range(3, 19)] + [[2., np.NaN]]
# Build array with sum
A = np.array(sum(X, []))
# Build array with concatenate
A = np.concatenate(X)
```

The latter is more readable.

For the second part, I would store indices of the user to which each data point belongs.

```
idx = np.concatenate([np.full(len(x), i, int) for i,x in enumerate(X)])
tr = np.nanpercentile(A,95)
ok = A < tr # this excludes outliers, +Inf and NaN
idx = idx[ok]
A = A[ok]
```

Finally, you can compute `x` from the range of `A`, then use `digitize` on `A` and get the bins of each element. Then each pair `(idx,bin-1)` identifies the datum of a given user belonging to a given bin. You can then sum all these contributions using the `at` method of the `ufunc` `add` ([see documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html)). Finally, you divide by the sum over bins to normalize.

```
x = np.linspace(A.min(), A.max(), 10+1)
bin = np.digitize(A, x)
Xn = np.zeros((len(X), len(x)))
np.add.at(Xn, (idx,bin-1), 1)
Xn /= Xn.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
```